# Custom tree structure in magento

Tags: magento

How to develop an interactive tree structure like Magento's product edit page tree structure. I displayed the category and sub-category by the following manner using `foreach` statement in a phtml file.

```
Select Categories *     

    Tourism
        Places
            test sub category
        Temples
        Hotels
        Map Image
    Entertainment
        Theatres
            movies
        Parks
        Temple Festivals
        Recent Movies
    Jobs
    Schools
        CBSE schools
```

I need this tree works like manage categories in magento backend.